# SpringBoot doesn't scan for components in microservices app

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'm coding microservices app based on Spring Cloud. I launched Eureka Server and now i'm coding a car-service. It worked when I didn't have any Autowiring in project. After adding Repository, Service and changing Controller the car-service doesn't launch.

When I added @SpringBootApplication("com.carrental.carservice.repository") application started but Rest API doesn't work and return 404. I tried with @Qualifier and naming Repository but still doesn't work. 
There is an error when starting:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.carrental.carservice.service.impl.CarTypeServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.carrental.carservice.repository.CarTypeRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.carrental.carservice.repository.CarTypeRepository' in your configuration.
```

And there is a WARN in logs:

```
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.carrental.carservice.repository.CarTypeRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

pom.xml of car service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>carrental</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.carrental</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>car-service</artifactId>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.199</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>





    </dependencies>


</project>
```

starting application file

```
package com.carrental.carservice;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
//@ComponentScan("com.carrental.carservice.repository")
public class CarServiceApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CarServiceApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

controller

```
package com.carrental.carservice.controller;


import com.carrental.carservice.dto.CarTypeDto;
import com.carrental.carservice.model.entity.CarType;
import com.carrental.carservice.service.CarTypeService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/car")
public class CarTypeController {

    private final CarTypeService carTypeService;

    @Autowired
    public CarTypeController(CarTypeService carTypeService){
        this.carTypeService = carTypeService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/cartype/add")
    public ResponseEntity<CarTypeDto> addCarType(@Valid @RequestBody CarTypeDto dto){
        CarType entity = Mapper.mapToCarTypeEntity(dto);
        this.carTypeService.add(entity);
        return new ResponseEntity<CarTypeDto>(Mapper.mapToCarTypeDto(entity), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String get(){
        return "jajo";
    }
}
```

service

```
package com.carrental.carservice.service.impl;

import com.carrental.carservice.model.entity.CarType;
import com.carrental.carservice.repository.CarTypeRepository;
import com.carrental.carservice.service.CarTypeService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class CarTypeServiceImpl implements CarTypeService {

    private final CarTypeRepository carTypeRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CarTypeServiceImpl(CarTypeRepository carTypeRepository){
        this.carTypeRepository = carTypeRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(CarType carType) {
        if(this.carTypeRepository.existsByName(carType.getName()))
            return;
        this.carTypeRepository.save(carType);
    }

    @Override
    public List<CarType> getAll() {
        return this.carTypeRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(CarType carType) {
        if(this.carTypeRepository.existsById(carType.getId()))
            this.carTypeRepository.save(carType);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(CarType carType) {
        this.carTypeRepository.delete(carType);
    }
}
```

repository

```
package com.carrental.carservice.repository;

import com.carrental.carservice.model.entity.CarType;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CarTypeRepository extends JpaRepository<CarType, Long> {
    boolean existsByName(String name);
    CarType getByName(String name);
    boolean existsById(Long id);
}
```

I tried a lot of stuff and still doesn't work. Can you help, please?

Comment: I have no idea why, but you have incompatible versions of libraries.

Comment: @spencergibb Which libraries? I tried to use the newest versions

Comment: @Kamilox Spring libraries. Instead of manually adding version of each Spring library, use something like `<parent>  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId> <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version> </parent>` in you maven build file, and remove the `<version>` tag from spring dependencies. Let Spring's dependency management resolve individual libraries for you (unless you have a strong reason to not do so).

Comment: You are mixing different versions of `spring-boot-starter` projects. For example you are using `2.0.9.RELEASE` version of spring-boot-starter-web and `2.1.4.RELEASE` of spring-boot-starter-data-jpa.

Comment: Also spring cloud 1.x libraries are not compatible with boot 2.x

Comment: "Rest API doesn't work and return 404", 404 means he can't find the resource you're asking for. Maybe you're getting the route you're taking wrong. Can you put the boot log and the request you make?

Comment: I changed dependency from ```<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> ```                                                                                                    to ```<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> ``` and it works. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to use feignClient to avoid this exception.i had similar issue and added
@EnableFeignClients to my ApplicationClass and its dependency to your pom

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId
</dependency>
```